# Scape % on java when querying

Tags: java

I have the following:

```
String value = Char;

query = query.replace("WHERE_PLACEHOLDER", "where lower(NAME) LIKE :value%");
```

I need the query at the end to say something like `abc%`, but the way it is, the value is not found, if I remove the `%` it works fine. I tried `\%` but then it doesn't find the value. This is the entire query:

```
SELECT *
FROM generic
WHERE name LIKE 'Char%'
```

How can I get that `%` to work on that query?

Comment: Which relational database are you working with?

Comment: Oracle SQL @GilbertLeBlanc

Comment: Based on [How to handle/use special characters like percent (%) and ampersand (&) in Oracle SQL queries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45446767) you may be looking for something along `.replace("WHERE_PLACEHOLDER", "where lower(NAME) LIKE :value\\% escape '\\' ");` (although I am not sure what you really want to achieve). Aside from that maybe `:value\\%` should be `':value\\%'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\` is a special character in Java Strings to you need to prefix it with another slash to escape itself.

```
query = query.replace("WHERE_PLACEHOLDER", "where lower(NAME) LIKE :value\\%");
```

The first pair escapes the `\` so you get `\%`

Comment: I need the `%` at the end of the string, take a look at the query above. I tried what you said: `\\\\%' but it can't find the value and also it adds `\\%` at the end

Comment: What about just adding two slashes `\\%`

Comment: With two `\\%` I get the value: `test\%` and it needs to be `test%`

Comment: Well, I am out of ideas.  I recommend you edit your question and add the front-end and database tags (all you have now is Java) so you get more visibility into this problem.  I'm sure someone knows how to solve it.

Comment: Let me brainstorm it a little more and if so I'll edit the question

Comment: I noticed that your actual query has single quotes in it but the Java String doesn't.  You can add them into the String if that would make a difference.

Comment: Check this out.  It may help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/863848/sign-in-javas-preparedstatement/864534#864534

Comment: Thanks for the tips, what I did was edit the front end and added the % if that form was being used, probably not the best strategy but for now it works. Here is how I did it with JQuery: `... ).val() + '%'),`